# Adding new "Files" related list to Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, chatter, related-list, chatter-file

I'm trying to add the new Chatter Files related list to a Visualforce page but not having much luck. In the past, in order to add the Notes & Attachments related list, you would use:

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!event}" list="CombinedAttachments" />
```

This still works, but I really want to leverage the new Winter '16 capability of better integrating attachments in the Feed with the record attachments. I've tried the following to no avail:

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!event}" list="Files" />
<apex:relatedList subject="{!event}" list="ChatterFiles" />
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hey looking into your question this is the solution for you.

You need to use `AttachedContentDocuments`

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:relatedList subject="{!Account.Id}" list="AttachedContentDocuments" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Amazing! I knew it was an easy answer, but am curious where you found it?

Comment: you can check in eclipse.